# Can't update a target table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one a options table (rot) that has the metrics of a set of rooms and another that has the current state of the rooms (rt).  I want to have a daily event that updates the cost_to_date in the rt using the values stored in the rot.

When I tried the SQL:

```
UPDATE room_tbl SET COST_TO_DATE_rt = COST_TO_DATE_rt + (
SELECT PerDiem_rot FROM room_options_tbl, room_tbl 
WHERE `ROOM_OPT_ID_rot` = `ROOM_OPT_ID_rt` 
    AND `ADULT_COUNT_rot` = `ADULT_COUNT_rt`)
```

I get the error: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'room_tbl' for update in FROM clause`

My searching for a solution led me to try a temporary table using aliasing but my attempts at it have all resulted in syntax errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like MySQL from the escaping

Comment: @therealmitchconnors based on the error its MySQL

Comment: Have you considered using a temp table for the subquery and then doing a simpler `update` statement from the temp table?

Comment: Make a stored procedure with the update statements in a transaction.

Comment: Jack Maney: my tries so far have been to do the temp table but can't make it work;  I keep getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a query because its not supported by MySQL in an update clause

From [13.2.10. UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Instead try the following

```
UPDATE room_options_tbl, room_tbl
SET COST_TO_DATE_rt = COST_TO_DATE_rt + PerDiem_rot 
WHERE `ROOM_OPT_ID_rot` = `ROOM_OPT_ID_rt` 
    AND `ADULT_COUNT_rot` = `ADULT_COUNT_rt`
```